# Extracting a record from pandas dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
**First_name Last_name  Policy_number**
David        Gilbert    IOTA123455
Fredrick     Manuel     IOTA367522
Donald       Trump      IOTA337823
Cathy        Jackso     IOTA892352
```

And I have a variable like this in my python program:

```
some_value = "Trump"
```

The "some_value" can take any value from any column from the above pandas dataframe. My query has to find in which column that some_value is, and return the record.

Say for ex, if `some_value = "Trump"`, my output should be:

```
 **First_name Last_name Policy_number**
    Donald       Trump      IOTA337823
```

Or if `some_value = "IOTA123455"`, my output should be:

```
**First_name Last_name  Policy_number**
David        Gilbert    IOTA123455
```

To achieve this, i have used the below code:

```
df.loc[(df['First_Name'].isin(some_value)) | df['Last_Name'].isin(some_values)] | df['Policy_Number'].isin(some_values)]
```

However i got the error as:

```
TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]
```

Is there any other way to solve this problem? Please help out.

Comment: For starters, just put: `some_value = ['Trump']`, your code will work.

Comment: You want `df.loc[(df==some_value).sum(axis=1).astype(bool)]`. This way you dont have to type out the same isin command for every single row.